# Non-blocking TCP socket fails to connect using socket2

Tags: sockets, rust

I am currently in the process of converting some of my code from blocking to non-blocking using the [`sockets2`](https://crates.io/crates/socket2) crate, however I am running into issues with connecting the socket. The socket always fails to connect before the timeout is exceeded. Despite my attempts to search for examples, I have yet to find any Rust code showing how a non-blocking TCP stream is created.

To give you an idea what I am attempting to do, the code I am currently converting looks looks roughly like this. This gives me no issues and works fine, but it is getting too costly to create a new thread for every socket.

```rust
let address = SocketAddr::from(([x, y, z, v], port));
let mut socket = TcpStream::connect_timeout(&address, timeout)?;
```

At the moment, my code to connect the socket looks like this. Since `connect_timeout` can only be executed in blocking mode, I use `connect` instead and regularly poll the socket to check if it is connected. At the moment, I keep getting `WouldBlock` errors when calling `connect`, but I do not know what this means. At first I assumed that the connect was proceeding, but returning the result immediately would require blocking so a `WouldBlock` error was given instead. However, due to the issues getting the socket to connect, I am second guessing those assumptions.

```rust
let address = SocketAddr::from(([x, y, z, v], port));

// Create socket equivalent to TcpStream
let socket = Socket::new(Domain::IPV4, Type::STREAM, Some(Protocol::TCP))?;

// Enable non-blocking mode on the socket
socket.set_nonblocking(true)?;

// What response should I expect? Do I need to bind an address first?
match socket.connect(&address.into()) {
    Ok(_) => {}
    Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
        // I keep getting this error, but I don't know what this means.
        // Is non-blocking connect unavailable?
        // Do I need to keep trying to connect until it succeeds?
    },
    // Are there any other types of errors I should be looking for before failing the connection?
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
}
```

I am also unsure what the correct approach is to determine if a socket is connected. At the moment, I attempt to read to a zero length buffer and check if I get a `NotConnected` error. However, I am unsure what `WouldBlock` means in this context and I have never gotten a positive response from this approach.

```rust
let mut buffer = [0u8; 0];

// I also tried self.socket.peer_addr(), but ran into issues where it returned a positive
// response despite not being connected.
match self.socket.read(&mut buffer) {
    Ok(_) => Ok(true),
    // What does WouldBlock mean in this context?
    Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => Ok(false),
    Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::NotConnected => Ok(false),
    Err(e) => Err(e),
}
```

Each socket is periodically checked until an arbitrary timeout is reached to determine if it has connected. **So far, no socket has passed the connected before reaching its timeout (20 sec) when connecting to a known-good server.** These tests are all performed in a single threaded application on Windows using a known-good server that has been checked to work with the blocking version of my program.

**Edit:** Here is a minimum reproducible example for this issue. However, it likely won't work if you run it on Rust playground due to network restrictions. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a08c22574a971c0032fd9dd37e10fd94

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a working main function and all the code required to hit your timeout. I'm afraid we can't help you if we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be setting `.set_nonblocking(true)` unless you know the implications of what it means. Consider the similar API from the Rust standard library for [`TcpStream::set_nonblocking()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_nonblocking) - operations will return a `WouldBlock` error *"if the IO operation could not be completed and needs to be retried"*.

Comment: @Finomnis I added an example, however you will need to create a local project and copy the code sample to run it due to network restrictions on Rust Playground.

Comment: Sure, that's no problem :)

Comment: So a couple of questions. Why exactly do you want nonblocking sockets? Are you sure you actually know what 'nonblocking' means? Are you sure you don't want to use tokio's async sockets instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WouldBlock` is the expected error when a **non-blocking** `connect()` (or other operation) is successfully started in the background. You can then wait up to your desired timeout interval for the operation to finish (use `select()` or `epoll()` or other platform-specific notification to detect this). If the timeout elapses, close the socket and handle the timeout accordingly. Otherwise, check the socket's `SO_ERROR` option to see if the operation was successful or failed, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I had the wrong assumption on how to receive messages and had manually put together a priority queue based on timeouts. I read some man pages related to `epoll` and it looks like it provides the functionality I was attempting to replicate with the priority queue. If anyone else happens to see this comment, the [`mio`](https://crates.io/crates/mio) crate offers documentation and examples which help explain how non-blocking code can be written.

Answer (score 0):

> To give you an idea what I am attempting to do, the code I am currently converting looks looks roughly like this. This gives me no issues and works fine, but it is getting too costly to create a new thread for every socket.

This sounds to me strongly like an XY-Problem.

I think you misunderstand what 'nonblocking' means. What it does **not** mean is that you can simply and without worrying run multiple sockets in parallel. What it **does** mean is that every operation that would block returns an error instead and you have to retry it at a later time.

Actual non-blocking sockets usually don't get used at enduser level. They are meant for libraries that depend on them and provide some higher level interface for asynchronism. Non-blocking sockets are hard to get right. They need to be paired with events, because otherwise you can only implement them with 100% cpu hungry busy loops, which is most likely not what you want.

There's good news, though! Remember the high-level libraries I talked about that use nonblocking sockets internally? The most famous one right now is called `tokio` and does exactly what you want. It will require you to learn a programming mechanism called `asynchronism`, but you will grasp it, I'm sure :)

I recommend this read: https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial